# How to set timing for threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am implementing a simple multi-threading example,in which Thread 1 prints PING after every 1000ms and Thread 2 prints PONG after every 2000ms.

```
public class T extends Thread 
{
public void run()
{
int i =10;
while(i>0)
{
    if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T1"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nPING");
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
    }
    else if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T2"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nPONG");
        try {Thread.sleep(2000);} 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
i--;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Thread t1 = new T();
    Thread t2 = new T();
    t1.setName("T1");
    t2.setName("T2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

But the output is like ::

PONG

PING

PING

PING

PONG

PING

PING

PONG

PING

PING

PONG

PING

PING

PONG

PING

PONG

PONG

PONG

PONG

PONG

But my expected output should be like

```
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG.....
```

What changes should be made in the code ?

Comment: You PING and PONG 10 times, but PING 2 times more often. So it should end with some PONGs

Comment: When Ping and Pong run at the same time, it is totally random which one is first. Both start at 0ms and "meet" every 2s. Please explain the intended model of behaviour, then we can propose an implementation.

Comment: I like these tasks, where someone tries to achieve something completely useless vis-a-vis real world apps. Or he/she/it is trying to achieve the desired and for some purpose useful behaviour in a terribly wrong way. What on earth could be the achievement of solving this task, except maybe learning that you should properly synchronize everything and otherwise let the thread execution flows run their natural way, instead of trying to be the thread-control-freak? My advice: Forget sleep() for sync. purposes, and learn how to do proper synchronization. You are choking your program to death.

Answer (score 4):

Say both threads start at time 0 and for whatever (thread scheduling) reason `PONG` starts first.

```
PONG (now wait 2000) // 0 has elapsed
PING (now wait 1000) // 0 has elapsed
PING (now wait 1000) // 1000 has elapsed
PING (now wait 1000) // 2000 has elapsed
PONG (now wait 2000) // 2000 has elasped
... and so on
```

If you want to `PING`s and then one `PONG`, consider using some notification mechanism (semaphore, coutdown latches, etc.). Don't rely on `sleep()`.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of [Thread.sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, **subject to the
>   precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.**

If you want to make sure the thread printing *PING* is run twice and then waits for the other thread to print *PONG* (and it in turn waits for two PINGS before proceeding), you need to synchronize the threads with each other. See [Object.wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) and [Object.notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29).

Edit: here's a version with synchronization (it's messy, but so is the original in the question ;P):

```
public class T extends Thread
{
    //Static object to synchronize on... bad practice but this is just an example anyway
    static Object synchOnMe = new Object();

    public void run()
    {
        int i = 10;
        while(i > 0)
        {
            if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T1"))
            {               
                System.out.println("PING");
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    //Synchronize on every second time (ie. wait for PONG)
                    if((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        synchronized(synchOnMe)
                        {
                            synchOnMe.notify();
                            synchOnMe.wait();
                        }
                    }                   
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T2"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //Synchronize every time (ie. wait for PING)
                    synchronized(synchOnMe)
                    {
                        synchOnMe.wait();
                        System.out.println("PONG");
                        synchOnMe.notify();
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            i--;
        }

        //One last notify to release the other thread waiting
        synchronized(synchOnMe)
        {
            synchOnMe.notify();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new T();
        Thread t2 = new T();
        t1.setName("T1");
        t2.setName("T2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
```

Comment: 1000ms is far above the precision of the OP sys, which is about 30ms, the answer is that pong by luck starts first

Comment: @AlexWien: You are using an real time operation system? There is no fixed precition, windows and "normal" linux grantees the threads to sleep at least X ms. Nothing else.

Comment: @AlexWien: Have you ever checked the output of `System.currentTimeMillis()` on a Windows-machine? The precision seems to be around 15-16ms. Don't know if it affects `Thread.sleep()`, but I wouldn't trust it being precise to a millisecond level, if threads need to work in tandem, synchronization has to be made in some other way than sleeping.

Comment: 1000ms is far above the precision of the OP sys, which is about 30ms, the answer is that pong by luck starts first. Altough you are correct that Thread syncronizing is missing.

Comment: @DanielR yes I have, and i have on embedded linux systems using java, too. you wroze 16ms, I wrote 30ms to be on the safe side. (although there is no garauntee)

Comment: @esaj, I wrote 1000ms and 30ms not 1ms, and in my answer I use 100ms

Comment: 1001ms+1000ms could be to much to run 'PING' twice between two 'PONG'. And 1ms is far below OS precision. @AlexWien: I never wrote 16ms,esaj wrote it.

Comment: Yes after 30 iterations, the cheap sleep() sync could not work anymore, but in the mean time it works.

Comment: @AlexWien: it's a local variable... both threads have their own copies

Comment: @AlexWien: Why 30 iteration? Lets assume it starts at: PING@0ms, PONG@1ms, PING@1001ms, PONG@2001ms, PING@2002ms. Explains the described output, assuming a jitter of 1ms.

Comment: @DanielR and AlexWien: I have no idea why are you arguing about this on the comments of my answer. Please go do it elsewhere, thank you  ;)

Comment: @DanielR read first my answer, ping and pong are output after the sleep(), so 0 and 1s will not happen

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ThreadPool from the newer concurrent package:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
System.out.println("\nPING or PONG");
```

after the `Thread.sleep()` not before.

or add a Thread.sleep() between the treads when you start them.

```
t1.start();
Thread.sleep(100);
t2.start();
```

(But I don't like the second solution)

Altough this is not a professional solution, it should work for about 30 iterations.
Later, since they are not proper synchronized this does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a for loop instead of a while loop.  It makes your intent much more clear.  Second, you need to understand that threads are not guaranteed to execute in the order you start them in.  All that's guaranteed is that the kernel will start allocating timeslices to the thread according to how the underlying operating system works and that the kernel will wait *at minimum* the amount of time you specify for the thread to sleep (sometimes it will be even less, if the kernel supports coalesced threads).

This means that T1 could in reality wait for 996 ms on a round and T2 could wait 2026 ms for another.  When I ran this code, for example, I got the following output:
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PING
PING
PONG
PONG
PONG
PONG
PONG

A bit of a mess.  Now, in many multithreaded applications this is okay when the threads are not dependent on each other.  If you want your output to line up the way you expect, though, then like the other answers suggest, you need to use wait() and notify().

For example, have T1 start, then have T1 start T2.  T2 should wait immediately on execution, then T1 should notify T2 each time it PINGs.  T2 can then count how many times it's received a notify and whenever the count is even, it can output a PONG.

I leave the implementation open as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not possible to have deterministic output (unless you ise some fancy real time technologies) in such case. It is due to the way how OS manages threads. The fact that thread has ended spleeping does not mean that it will receive CPU time immediately.

The only way to have deterministic ordering of thread execution is to use synchronization between them. Use google to learn more as this is pretty complicated matter.

Comment: Also note, that even threads start order is not deterministic (as you have seen) - determinism may be achieved only by synchronization.